# IE 11 Metro does not download script

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am hosting a javascript file on a subdomain of our main website.  When browsing the site using IE 11 metro/touch the file does not get downloaded.  I am assuming it is not being downloaded because a graphic it renders does not appear.  However, if I put the URL of the script in the address bar and download it, then go back to my main site, the script does download and render the graphic.

I tried debugging this with Fiddler, but when Fiddler is up, it works without issue.  Shut fiddler down, refresh the page, and I am back to square 1 and the graphic does not show (or file is not downloaded).

What causes this?  I assume its a setting in IE, but I cannot not find it anywhere.